# How to send log4j2 generated log files to AWS cloudwatch and S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, log4j2, java-ee-7, logfile, amazon-cloudwatch

I have two log4j2 generated log files. I am generating these log files using FileAppender and now I want to send those log files to AWS cloudwatch and S3 bucket as a log4j2 destination.

I am new to log4j2 and this cloud API. I have searched a lot but not able to find something useful. Though I have found these two links:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-configuration-cwl.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-logging.html

But I am not sure how it will work and whether Is this the only way to send log files to AWS cloudwatch and S3 bucket. And What other settings do I need to do in my log4j2.xml file.

So, how to send log4j2 generated log files to cloud API? I have to use log4j2 and J2EE.

Here is my log4j2.xml file:

```
<Configuration monitorInterval="30" status="warn" name= "MyApp" packages="" xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config">

<Properties>
    <Property name="filename-server1-all">${sys:catalina.home}/logs/server1-all.log</Property>
    <Property name="filename-server1-err">${sys:catalina.home}/logs/app.log</Property>
    <Property name="pattern_layout">%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </Console>

    <File name="appender-server-1-all" fileName="${filename-server1-all}">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern_layout}" />
    </File>

    <File name="appender-server1-err" fileName="${filename-server1-err}">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern_layout}" />
    </File>
 </Appenders>

       <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="appender-server-1-all" level="all"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="appender-server1-err" level="error"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
   </Configuration>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code of what you have tried, and what you have so far?

Comment: I have added my log4j2.xml file. But I am not sure now how to proceed further to send these log files to aws cloudwatch or S3 bucket from here.

Comment: @A.S Did you find the solution ?